# C# Generic method return type from list of Types

Tags: c#, generics, return-type

My problem involves this code:

```
public static class MyStaticClass {
    public class MyClass {
        public List<object> MyObjects;
        public List<Type> MyTypes;

        public MyClass() {
            MyObjects = new List<object>(){ 1, 0.5F };
            MyTypes = new List<Type>(){ typeof{int), typeof(float) }
        }

        public T GetObject<T>(int index) {
            // Should return an instance of type MyTypes[index], and not object
            return MyObjects[index] as MyTypes[index];
        }
    }

    public static void Main() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        int arg1 = myClass.GetObject(0);
        float arg2 = myClass.GetObject(1);
        MyMethod(arg1, arg2);
    }

    public static void MyMethod(int arg1, float arg2) {
        // Does something
    }
}
```

I want `MyClass` to store a list of mixed types and with variable length. The only way I know to do this is by storing a `List<object>`. However, I want to use the values of `MyClass.MyObjects` in a method, but if I simply get the values as `object`, then it sends an error that it cannot convert object to int, float, etc...

The problem is that I know the exact subtypes of the objects in `MyObjects`, but I cannot find a way to set `T` in `MyClass.GetObject` to the type `MyTypes[index]`. The only solution I have found is to use

```
int arg1 = myClass.MyObjects[0] as int;
float arg2 = myClass.MyObjects[1] as float;
```

However, I would like it to be that I only have to set the types of the objects once and then just use `MyTypes` to cast the objects in `MyObjects` automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Calling method still should know what type is stored at each index. What you are trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: So why isn't just casting to `T` enough? (Yes, that's legal, the conversion will happen at runtime.) Do you expect the need to detect a mismatch between `T` and `MyTypes[index]`?

Comment: Even if you *could* cast within your method the calling code still must have to know the type to pass as generic parameter. But if your calling code knows the actual type anyway I can´t see the problem on casting the returned object to that specific type

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to not code to an interface instead of worrying about unboxing `object`s?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I guess OP wants to *not* pass the generic type-param on his own but the runtime to set it appropriately to what `myTypes[inex]` returns.

Comment: You're already using it as generic, so the type is already infered, just do `return (T)MyObjects[index]`

Comment: @HimBromBeere: that already happens when you return `object`. The runtime type will be exactly what the object is. But then, of course, the caller has no static type information. My question is intended to tease out what the OP is actually after.

Comment: What you´re trying to do is simply not possible, as your `MyObjects`-list is just a list of `object`. You *have* to cast the elements in your calling code to their actual type - either within the method using the generic type-parameter (which you have to provide in calling code) or in your calling code (where you have to provide the type also).

Comment: why not simply use `int arg1 = myClass.Foo; float arg2 = myClass.Bar;` Is there some advantage of using indexes and casting instead of property names?

Comment: @HimBromBeere If that is the case, then it's unfortunate that it can't be done automatically

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I don't know how many objects I want to store and what types they have until I instantiate MyClass

Comment: @Marijn you are using local variables, which should be defined before you even compile your code. That will happen long time before you'll instantiate MyClass. How you will know how many local variables you need?

Comment: I think I know where the mistake is. If I have a method with a signature that requires e.g. an `int`, then the compiler cannot know whether the object has been cast to an `int` if all I have done was cast an object to some `Type` (even though the `Type` refers to `int`). What worked for me was to create a copy of `MyMethod` that takes only `object`s, then in that method it casts to the subtypes and then runs `MyMethod` with the subtype signature.

Comment: The correct way to indicate that your question has been successfully answered is to accept an answer. If there isn't currently an answer that matches what solved your question, then you should consider *adding* an answer of your own and then accepting it. Not to edit the title of your question or to include your attempt at an answer within the body of the *question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know where the mistake is. If I have a method with a signature that requires e.g. an `int`, then the compiler cannot know whether the object has been cast to an `int` if all I have done was cast an object to some `Type` (even though the `Type` refers to `int`). What worked for me was to create a copy of `MyMethod` that takes only `objects`, then in that method it casts to the subtypes and then runs `MyMethod` with the subtype signature.

Answer (score 0):

Storing types is redundant as each object already has stored type information within itself.

You can cast the result or define the type explicitly, here's the latter:

```
public static class MyStaticClass {
    public class MyClass {
        public List<object> MyObjects;

        public MyClass() {
            MyObjects = new List<object>(){ 1, 0.5F };
        }

        public T GetObject<T>(int index) {
            var item = MyObjects[index];
            if(typeof(T) != item.GetType())
                throw new InvalidCastException();

            return (T) item;
        }
    }

    public static void Main() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        int arg1 = myClass.GetObject<int>(0);
        float arg2 = myClass.GetObject<float>(1);
        MyMethod(arg1, arg2);
    }

    public static void MyMethod(int arg1, float arg2) {
        // Does something
    }
}
```

You can use GetType() on any object, so if you have a collection of unknown objects, you can just figure their types out at run-time and act accordingly.